# scan the network for a server while using AsyncSocket as a client

Tags: objective-c, networking, asyncsocket

My app communicates with an external server using AsyncSocket as a Client.
(the working code can be found [here](https://github.com/mikeooye/BPSocketClient)) 
When the app starts, the user types in the IP address of the server computer.

*assuming both iOS and server is sitting on the same subnet*

[image]

**Question:** is there a way to "scan" the network for the server thus avoiding the user manual input for server IP ?

I can iterate the IPs one by one in a loop  (10.0.1.x  10.0.1.x++)
yet it seems wrong and wasteful.

is there another more elegant way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I had an iOS project doing server discovery in the current (Wi-Fi) network. The typical solution is to use UDP broadcasting to ask for server info and then listen to a UDP response. As soon as you get the response with the server address you can establish connection using TCP sockets.

[CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) is good enough for this. I used `GCDAsyncUdpSocket` and `GCDAsyncSocket`.

I understand you probably need more info on the topic. I'll try to extend the answer when I have time to.

Comment: Please do, I still don't have a good solution for network discovery.